# How to import the mysql library the right way in D?

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors, d

I am trying to connect to the mysql database at localhost with D but when i want to compile my code i am getting the following error from the terminal:

> module `mysql` is in file 'mysql.d' 
>   which cannot be readimport path[0] = /Library/D/dmd/src/phobos 
>   import path[1] = /Library/D/dmd/src/druntime/import

```
#!/usr/bin/env dub

import mysql;
void main (){
//Connect
con = new Connection("host=localhost; port =3306; user=root; pwd=password; db=awesomeschema");
scope(exit) con.close();


if (con.closed()){ 
    writeln("connected"); 
    } else {
        writeln("conn closed");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example has no dependencies listed.
No Mysql client library has been requested. Hence it fails to compile.

Comment: I think the question is how to do the dependencies.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe could you tell me more about dependencies and yes you're right i dont know how to link them.